# How to display date as mm/dd/yyyy without time in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs, date

I can't get my date to display without the time in an HTML table.
This is my code.

```html
<td input type={Date}>{call.date}</td>
```

The date gets entered by a Date Picker as mm/dd/yyyy but us displayed like this 
    2019-09-25T00:00:00

Answer (score 6):

a JS date will always contain the time data even if you didn't provide the time, for the display of the datepicker depends on the datepicker settings/configurations. or you can handle it manually on your side too.

if `call.date` is a string and contains ISO Date string, then you can do this to display date without time:

```
<td input type={Date}>{call.date.substring(0, 10)}</td>
```

or other ways:

```
// Parse into JS date object
const date = new Date(call.date)
...
<td input type={Date}>{date.toISOString().substring(0, 10)}</td>
```

Comment: `{variableDate.substring(0, 10)}` works for me on list or edit input. thanks a million @Jee Mok. this should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use `normal javascript`, **or** `moment.js` you could `import`

Vanilla javascript:

```
let today = new Date();  // get the date
let day = ("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2);  //get day with slice to have double digit day
let month = ("0" + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); //get your zero in front of single month digits so you have 2 digit months
let date = month + '/' + day + '/' + today.getFullYear();
```

Then

```
<td input type={Date}>{date}</td>
```